# Grafana custom data source

Tags: grafana

help me with this fairly new to Grafana

Things accomplished so far:
1. Managed to get a JSON output from CSV (basically looking to plot transaction availability based on success/ fail criteria)
2. Wanted a Prometheus source imported

Can you help me how I proceed in either building a Graphite dashboard (or) Prometheus? Much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Has anyone been able to use JSON exporter to scrape JSON data published online?

Answer (score 1):

## In order to use Prometheus datasource, you need to follow below steps

1. Start Prometheus server. By default, it listens at 9090 port.
2. login to Grafana console, go to option - Add datasource
3. select Prometheus as type of datasource from the drop down.
4. Insert the Prometheus URL (You got this in step 1)
5. Access should be "direct" if you aren't using any proxy to establish connection.
6. Hit save & test.